# Add input if last input existing has value (Javascript, jQuery & HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I would like to make a poll script and need to add an input when the last input that already exists has a value. So if someone was to enter something into the second input a third would appear and if something was entered in the third input a fourth and so on.

Here are the inputs:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="animated fadeInUp normal" type="text" name="option[]" placeholder="Your Option 1" required />
<input autocomplete="off" class="animated fadeInUp normal" type="text" name="option[]" placeholder="Your Option 2" required />
```

I also have jQuery loaded, so that's probably the way to do it.

I hope this was understandable...
Thanks.

Comment: what if the user enters value in the second input - but the first is blank?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('input', 'input', function() {
    if ( $('input:last').get(0) === this && this.value.length ) {
        $('body').append( $('<input />', {
            type: 'text',
            'class' : 'animated fadeInUp normal',
            placeholder : 'Your Option ' + ($('input').length + 1)
        }) );
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2D4Gs/)

Comment: it's not recommended to bind event on whole document. it would be better to bind it on some div

Comment: There was no parent given, so I bound the event to something that existed.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div id='input-container'>
    <input type='text'>
</div>
```

js

```
var container = $('#input-container').on('click', 'input:last', function(){
   container.append('<input type="text">');
})
```

you can try to use other events. for example `.on('input'...)`

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/LjdcB/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/w67r5/)**</kbd>

```
i = 3;
$(document).on('change','.normal', function() {
  if($(this).val() !== '' && $(this).next('.normal').length < 1) {
     $(this).after('<input autocomplete="off" class="animated fadeInUp normal" type="text" name="option[]" placeholder="Your Option '+ i++ +'" required />');
  }
});
```

or little improved

```
i = 3;
$(document).on('change','.normal', function() {
  // Add inputs and limit their number
  if($(this).val() !== '' && $('.normal').length < 5 && $(this).next('.normal').length < 1) {
     $(this).after('<input autocomplete="off" class="animated fadeInUp normal" type="text" name="option[]" placeholder="Your Option '+ i++ +'" required />');
  }
  // Add Submit button after last input
  if($('.normal').length === 5 && $('.submit').length === 0) {
     $('.normal:nth-child('+$('.normal').length+')').after('<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />');
  }
});
```